# How do I create a Azure AD service principal in our customer’s tenant without having global admin rights

Tags: azure-active-directory

We are using service principal to connect our Azure tenant with our customer’s tenant. To create the service principal in customer’s tenant, we need global admin of the customer’s AD tenant to approve and create the service principal. We are trying to find a way to accomplish this without using global admins involvement. The solution can involve few manual steps which can be done at customer’s end.

Answer (score 0):

You could ask an admin of your customer's tenant to configure the **User settings**.

Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#check-azure-ad-permissions).

> Check the **App registrations** setting. This value can only be set by an
>   administrator. If set to **Yes**, any user in the Azure AD tenant can
>   register an app.

Then you could use a non-admin account to create the service principal.

---

**UPDATE**

I'm afraid that you have to use a global admin to do the admin consent because the permissions are for the entire tenant.

I don't think a global admin need to do this all the time. Every time new permissions are assigned to your app, administrator consent is required.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Allen. Appreciate the quick response. Actually I did not put the full requirement correctly. Here is one more addition. Thanks!!!

[Screenshot: Access Grants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK6BF.png)

The service principal requires delegated access to APIs as shown in the diagram. That appears, that it can be granted by global admin. Can any other user(s)/ roles can do this? What is the best practice for this. We are trying to avoid to have a global admin to do this all the time and wanted to have someone in the project team to own this process.

Appreciate any insights.

Comment: See my update in my answer. You should never add an answer if it's not one. You can edit your original post to add additional information.